# How to: CRUD for custom post types in the front end?

Tags: custom-post-types

Is there an easy way to modify custom post types on the frontend? Maybe you can direct me to a plugin?

For example, I have a custom post type called "Product". The examples I see online show how I can perform CRUD on products in the dashboard, but is there a way I let a user modify a product on the frontend of the site?

Do I need to write my own crud code for the front end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm from the World of Django, where CRUD is King, so I had a similar question. The best answer I've found so far is [Pods](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/) and the associated [Pods UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods-ui/). Unlike "Custom Posts", which are kind of weird once you take a look under the hood, Pods actually creates real tables with real fields. Furthermore, you can crate *relations*! What a concept! Try that with Custom Fields. I haven't done this for a user-facing page yet, but it makes for a very nice admin-facing input form.

*Update in response to comment:*

WP doesn't really have an ORM to speak of. It has `meta` tables (`wp_usermeta`, `wp_postmeta`, and `wp_commentmeta`) to store "extra" information in (this is where new fields are stored for Custom Post Types), but there is none of the very nice lazy-dereferencing you have in a proper ORM.

Although relationships (foreign key, one-to-one, and many-to-many) are not natively supported by WP, there are a handful of plugins that address this issue and one of them that may make this situation palatable for you. I haven't used any of them (yet) so I can't speak for their relative strengths and weaknesses.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/ This plugin is by [scribu](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts/p2p-0-5.html), one of the WP core developers. I don't if that makes it better, but it's a data point.
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relation-post-types/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-relationships/

Comment: This is a really good find.  I'll definitely give it a test run and get back to you. Custom Post Types does not allow for relational mapping? That might be a deal breaker for me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: @Peter Rowell - I came to WordPress from Drupal which inspired Pods; prior to that with ~15 years of relational database design experience. At first I saw WordPress' approach as a negative but after working with it for two years I've come to prefer it *in most cases.* The reality is it just works better most of the time. Yes, it is not as elegant nor is it as performant or robust for well-defined scenarios but like a dynamic languages vs. statically-typed languages it's more flexible and easier to implement on an ad-hoc basis and that frequently that trumps the more structured alternative.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I'll confess to not having done any specific performance testing of one method versus the other. I think my major complaint is that using the meta tables doesn't fit the way my (admittedly aging) brain works and there is zero syntactic sugar to keep me from rubbing my face in it. I have a project coming up for a large, private collection of lute music (yes, really) and if I have time I'll try doing and A-B comparison of the two in terms of performance.

Comment: @Peter Rowell - Nice to have you here; finally, someone older than me! :)  I think you'll find that performance wise it is slower, but that the sites where it matters that it's slower is a small subset of total sites. Frankly what I would like to see is the ability to start with WordPress' meta approach but transition seamlessly to Pods when it's needed. I'm actually working on a project where that might be viable.  BTW, I envy you being about to work in Python, my 2nd favorite language *(PHP is 3rd, or worse in my book)* but my life path just hasn't taken me there.

Comment: @Peter Rowell - Also you are the first advocate for another platform that I think I've seen answering questions here. Yes, Django is awesome but WordPress has it's strengths too. We are trying to build a community based on the positive so please cut our WordPress some slack when it's not perfect. It has definite strengths in areas Django is weaker *(minimally such as # of available plugins and themes)* and my guess is you may come to even appreciate some of those things that turned you off at first, like I have. :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - I wasn't so much advocating for Django as explaining where I was coming from in terms of my expectations. The reason I am here at all is that it's getting harder to find websites that need $20,000-$40,000 worth of engineering work that are willing to deal with a solo contractor. WordPress, regardless of its faults, represents an ecosystem that is probably 500-1,000 *times* larger than Django's. There are parts of the WP architecture that are much more inviting than Django (and parts that aren't). FWIW, I'm 61 and have been hacking for 38 years this month. AKA, a Geezer Geek:-)

Comment: @Peter Rowell - Agreed, and again, very glad to have you here! I know what you mean. WordPress is becoming the *"plug-and-play"* solution for businesses who need a standard website. Yes, I saw your age on your profile; you can see my age on mine. :)  BTW, if you are interested in doing hard core engineering but on WordPress, we might have an opportunity for that later in the year. As they used to say in TV, *"Stay tuned..."* :)

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Always interested in an opportunity.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: So, is there a simple way to perform CRUD in the front end for a custom post type?  Reading from the conversation above, you found a faster way of doing this without resorting to custom tables like what PODS uses.

Answer (score 0):

I know plugin [Front-end Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) that allows to edit different things on front-end, but not sure how compatible it is with custom post types.

Comment: it doesn't look like it's compatible with Custom Post Types. I'll give it a try after I take PODS for a spin. Thank You.